# GetHashCode() for long primitive

Tags: c#, .net, iequalitycomparer

I am writing a EqualityComparer for a LINQ distinct expression and I am not too sure about the GetHashCode overload method. Would the below code be correct? The Id property is a long primitive.

```
public int GetHashCode(Deal obj)
{
   return ((int)obj.Id) ^ ((int)(obj.Id >> 32)); ;
}
```

Comment: The answer depends on what you are comparing in the `Equals` method. Why not just `return obj.Id.GetHashCode()`?

Comment: I am just comparing with == operator for Equals method. I do not really need the hashcode in my context but I was just hoping to get clarification on the long primitive since there is a loss in precision.

Comment: comparing what with `==`? the `Id`? If so you are fine although `obj.Id.GetHashCode()` would be simpler. My point is that there are certain invariants `GetHashCode` and `Equals` must satisfy as part of the `IEqualityComparer<T>` contract. In particular, `GetHashCode(x) != GetHashCode(y)` implies `Equals(x, y)` is false. The LINQ `Distinct` method requires both to be implemented correctly. Eric Lippert has an exhaustive list of guidelines if you are interested: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Answer (score 13):

Probably you should check whether `obj` is not null. In case of null return `0`. Honestly your implementation for `long` Id is completely the same as .NET Framework `GetHashCode` for `long` data type. In other words you can simply call `obj.Id.GetHashCode()` after not null checking.